# Order collection by points using Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I have a collection where I get the points for each player.

```
        $rankings = Player::with(['rankings'])
              ->map(function($item){
                   return ['points' => $item->rankings->pluck('points')];
               })->sortByDesc('total');
```

This gives me back the following:

```
            [
                {
                    "player": 5,
                    "points": [
                        4,
                        2,
                        1,
                        2,
                        2,
                        3
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "player": 1,
                    "points": [
                        2,
                        3,
                        3,
                        4,
                        4,
                        4
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "player": 10,
                    "points": [
                        1,
                        4,
                        2,
                        1,
                        1,
                        2
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "player": 6,
                    "points": [
                        3,
                        1,
                        1,
                        3,
                        3,
                        1
                    ]
                }
        ]
```

How can I sort the collection so that the players who score the most points 1? The ones with the most 2 points remaining second and so on? And in case there are players tied in points 1, get those who have more points 2?

```
            [
                {
                    "player": 10,
                    "points": [
                        1,
                        4,
                        2,
                        1,
                        1,
                        2
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "player": 6,
                    "points": [
                        3,
                        1,
                        1,
                        3,
                        3,
                        1
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "player": 5,
                    "points": [
                        4,
                        2,
                        1,
                        2,
                        2,
                        3
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "player": 1,
                    "points": [
                        2,
                        3,
                        3,
                        4,
                        4,
                        4
                    ]
                },
        ]
```

Thanks.